# Decrementing (DEX/DEY Opcodes) when X and Y are 0 for 6502 Cpu

Tags: emulation, opcode, nintendo, 6502

I'm currently attempting to write an NES emulator through .NET and I have a question about the particular opcodes that do decrementing and incrementing...

Since X, and Y registers are 8 bits, in terms of implementation, is it an unsigned or signed byte? That is, is the value range of the X and Y registers from -128 to 127 or 0-255?

I am confused by this because if the X and Y registers are initialized as 0, what happens when a DEX is performed? Or is it up to the programmer to actually worry about that?

Thanks in advance for the help everyone.

Comment: It's not directly part of your question, and Dougvj's point about two's complement arithmetic is worth absorbing, but X and Y are considered to be unsigned since e.g. `LD X,$FF` then `LD $5200,X` will load from $52FF, not from $51FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough with two's complement signed numbers there is no difference when performing arithmetic, therefore DEX is agnostic as to whether the register contains a signed or unsigned number. For example, the bits representing -1 are the same as those representing 255. So 0 - 1 = 255 or -1 depending on your interpretation. The decrementation doesn't care.

Comment: I see, so this means it is actually the SIGN bit from the status register that gets read that determines if it is actually a negative?

Comment: Yes, which is equivalent to the highest order bit (so 127 = 01111111; 128 - 256 = 1XXXXXXX = -126 - -1) Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, this definitely does make sense to me now. Thank you for your answer!